# Can I re marry first wife when I'm still with second wife?

Tags: talaq, husband-wife

Asalam valikum,

I got khula from my first wife 8 years ago and have a son of 7 years, she is unmarried till now and I got married to another girl and have 3 kids, now can I re marry my first wife by not getting separated from my second wife. Can I be with both wifes at the same time. As I do not want to leave my second wife and recently my first wife mother died. So I want to try and get back my first wife and take care of her and my son. Is that possible.

Comment: Please be aware that this is not a fatwa site. Answers should be judged by the evidence they provide. Without evidence, it’s just the guess of a random person on the Internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it but better to discuss the same with knowledgeable person in your town/city/family. Make sure to keep involve all your relatives.

It is legal in Islam, but just to `take care`? you can do it without marrying, is not that true?

Better to discuss you current wife and family first before asking to anyone else...